# Style not being applied correctly to Navbar React component

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-jsx

I'm learning Next.js — currently on version `10.0.3`. I'm using `react-bootstrap` version `1.4.0` and `classnames` version `2.2.6`.

I'm using one component (`Navbar`) that I'm trying to apply certain styles to, but so far it isn't working. This is what I have so far:

```js
// ~/project-name/components/Header.tsx
import classnames from "classnames";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

import styles from "./Header.module.css";

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar className={classnames(styles.borderBottom, styles.boxShadow)} bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Link href="/" passHref>
            <Navbar.Brand><span className="font-weight-bold">./shīdo.io</span></Navbar.Brand>
          </Link>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="id-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="id-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-5 mr-auto">
              <Link href="/" passHref>
                <Nav.Link active>Home</Nav.Link>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/features" passHref>
                <Nav.Link>Features</Nav.Link>
              </Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav>
              <Link href="/login" passHref>
                <Nav.Link>Login</Nav.Link>
              </Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

```css
# ~/project-name/components/Header.module.css
@charset "UTF-8";

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

The issue is that `border-bottom` and `box-shadow` are not being applied to the resulting `nav` HTML tag in the final document. Any help will be appreciated.

> I've also tried to use ``` <style jsx>{``}</style> ``` (with the same styles) within the same `Header.tsx` component, but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: What happens if you pass the styles as regular string like className='border-bottom box-shadow' in the Navbar component?

Comment: The styles then are _applied_ to the `nav` HTML element effectively, but I can't really see that it changes anything. Basically, in that way, I see the classes being applied correctly, but not what I would expect they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS class names are not picking up. you may try giving like below:

```
className={classnames(styles['border-bottom'], styles['box-shadow'])}>
```

React updates the provided user stylesheet class names with their updated names if seen in the developer console.

Not sure if that answers your doubt but you can try something like this for selecting that element through class name:

```
[class^="Header_border-bottom"] or [class*="Header_border-bottom"]
```

Comment: This works and the styles are being applied correctly. The only downside is that the class names are _slightly_ borked: `Header_border-bottom__3fKl3 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark`. If you know a way to have those like they should be, would you mind updating the answer if there is a way?